# Loop array values and put them in new option attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array and i would like to fetch only the values of this array and put them in an existing select element. See my current code:

```
var obj = [
    {
        "-": "",
        "0": "1",
        "1": "value1",
        "2": "value2",
        "3": "value3",
        "4": "value4",
        "5": "value5",
        "6": "value6",
        "7": "value7",
        "8": "value8"
    }
];

var windings_array = [];
for (elem in obj) {
   windings_array.push(obj[elem]);
}

var options = $("#winding").find("option");
for (var idx in windings_array) {
    options.eq(idx).attr("img-data", JSON.stringify(windings_array[idx]));
};
```

Problem is, only the first option element gets changed and the complete array gets injected in "img-data".

```
<option img-data="value1"></option>
<option img-data="value2"></option>
<option img-data="value3"></option>
...
```

How should i do this?

Comment: what is the desired output

Comment: <option img-data="value3"></option>

So an extra attr "img-data" each with the values from the array.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RW2hj/2/

Comment: there is no way you will be able to guess the order in which the values will be set